# Paypal PDT doesn't work with free trial

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm implementing paypal free trial with Paypal PDT. According to Paypal docs "*When a customer pays you, PayPal sends the transaction ID of the payment to you by appending the transaction ID to a URL you specify in your account Profile. This information is sent via a HTTP GET*". I have GET results when transaction is not free, however on free trial PDT doesn't returns any GET/POST variables.

Is it possible to use Paypal PDT on free trials?
Any hints/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

added note:

- My Auto Return is set to ON
- I have specified a Return URL
- Payment Data Transfer is set to ON

Answer (score 1):

PDT does work with each transaction. But it has a few shortcomings that prevent it from being reliably used as a sole solution for postpayment processing. Two specific times when PDT does not prove to be an optimal solution is when you are paid with an eCheck and when your user browses away from the PayPal payment confirmation screen before being redirected back to your site. You are advised to use IPN for the alternative method.

But each transaction in PayPal is requested to have an amount, and then transaction ID will be created. But for the 'free trial' you mentioned, do you mean that there is No amount in the transaction? If it is, what type of this transaction and how did you create it?

Comment: yes, i mean no amount ($ 0) , as in Free, and after 30 days user will be given a chance to subscribe for $20. Sorry if i miss something im new at Paypal. I just created it using the merchant button. Anyway my specs changed from the client, so there would be no more Free Trial. And thanks for clarifying, i should just use IPN.  Plus point!